# Terraform, how to append passed-in string variable to a value?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform v0.12.17

I have a script where I want to do this, that is, I want it to search AMIs with a passed-in `jenkins_version` variable

```
$ terraform plan -var "jenkins_version=2.249.3" -out out.output

data "aws_ami" "jenkins_master_ami" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["packer-jenkins-master-${var.jenkins_version}"]
  }
  owners = ["1234567890"]
}
```

In my example, I want it to give me the AMI with name `packer-jenkins-master-2.249.3` which I know exists because I just created it, and with the correct owner. However I get an error, since I obviously have the wrong syntax. What's the correct syntax?

```
Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
```

Comment: If you skip the `filter`, does it return anything?

Comment: Your syntax is correct. Please check region and account used to create ami and run terraform.

Comment: @Marcin thanks, your comment made me realized my error. I was searching for the tag "Name" I gave it, instead of the actual AMI name I gave it when I created the AMI (with Packer), which are different.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I can provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

I **verified** the `data.aws_ami.jenkins_master_ami` using my own sandbox account, and the data source definition is correct.

It returns AMI named `packer-jenkins-master-2.249.3` as expected, if it exists in the given region and account.